# Delete ListView row in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to delete a row from my list view on click of "delete" button. My listview item has following things placed horizontally: TextView-1,TextView-2,TextView-3,ImageButton-delete button. Now when I click delete button, the row should be deleted from the view. Below is the adapter code;

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View view = (View) v.getParent();
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            String item = tv.getText().toString();
            String tableno = mListItems.get(0).getTableNumber();

            orderDetailsDB = new OrderDetailsDBAdapter( 
                    getApplicationContext());

            orderDetailsDB.deleteItem(item,tableno);
```

I tried by setting Individual textviews to blank but its not working.

```
holder.itemName.setText("");
holder.amount.setText("");
holder.quantity.setText("");
```

I read couple of posts and they suggest to remove item from my list(mListItems) and then do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Problem is I am not using array adapter for populating list view but using Custom adapter, so unable to get the position for item to be deleted. Please advise. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First write below line in your adapter's `getView` method.

```
button.setTag(position)
```

in `onClick` method

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
                yourarraylistObject.remove(position);
               // your remaining code
                notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use remove() to remove list item from the adapter

for your reference

```
adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        adb.setTitle("Delete?");
        adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
        final int positionToRemove = position;
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }});
        adb.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: We are not using setOnItemClickListener ,instead of this we arae using setonClicklistener

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in order to get the position that you want to delete is to pass that into your listener:

```
// inside custom adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
.....
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(position);
}
private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
int position = -1;
public MyClickListener(final int position)
{
     this.position = position;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     // do your delete code here
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```